# Windows 8.1 tips wont go away when clicked

Tags: windows-8.1

i have a hp laptop running windows 8.1 with tips appearing on the sides and corners. So far I've gotten a few to disappear but this one is staying. Its telling me about switching between apps by putting my cursor into the top left corner and clicking but when i do so, nothing happens.

Here is a screen-shot I took:

[image: http://prntscr.com/8a2mgl]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Eightforums posted a guide](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/31098-help-tips-enable-disable-windows-8-1-a.html) on how to do remove them

Run the **Group Policy Editor** (`gpedit.msc`), go to `User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Edge UI` and set the option `Disable help tips` to `enabled`.

[image]

Now log off and login again and the tips are gone.